# using histogram distances for clustering

Tags: clustering, histogram, eigenvalues

Business context: for our retail client there are a few crucial products. All of them have 3 phases (introduction, stable phase and end of life). After correcting for seasonality and discounts (as much as possible) we used the weekly sales % change and tried to fit a distribution to it. Not surprisingly non gaussian but it even escaped Poisson. The end goal is to ensure that other products (that the client is having trouble in categorizing) can be modeled using these as proxies.

Statistical solutions (so far): I used histograms for each phase and calculated the histogram distances (used EMD) and generated a matrix which indicates the distance of each phase's distribution from the other. 
ex : matrix(0,0) = 123, matrix(0,1) = 2560, matrix(0,3) = 288 , matrix(1,3)= 300

I would like to use this signature (assuming I have used all available data points to generate the histograms above) to assign other products (also please note that the "other" products also have just been introduced, hence haven't seen a complete life cycle yet) the appropriate signature so that the planners have a good idea about their volumes.

Question : can I generate an eigenvector for the square matrix generated above (in the example matrix) so I can use this in clustering eigenvectors generated from the other products? given that clustering distance matrices is a little befuddling to me.

Comment: i always ensure i add "hey folks" at the beginning and SO always eats it up :) ..makes me sound a little rude..any pointers on that will also help

Comment: When you say SO, you perhaps mean SE. No experienced user here will infer rudeness from lack of personal greetings. On the contrary, technical questions without unnecessary extra words are strongly preferred here.

Comment: See e.g. http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated for some advice. Note that "i" for the personal pronoun "I" is far from standard. More importantly, you have no need to apologise for or explain your personal background: many people here (including myself) are not statisticians.